# Conversion from S3ObjectInputStream to AbstractStreamResource

Tags: java, amazon-s3, vaadin

I am getting an AWS S3 image resource as a S3ObjectInputStream and want to put it into a Vaadin image HTML Component. The Vaadin Image only has two ways of initialization. The first is through a string indicating a filepath, which would mean writing the S3 image to disk, which I cannot do because of data security reasons and the second one is through something implementing "AbstractStreamResource". The question now is, how do I get the S3ObjectInputStream converted to something implementing "AbstractStreamResource" to keep the file only in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [S3ObjectInputStream  API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html) S3ObjectInputStream is sub class of java.io.InputStream. In that case you should be able to do

```
    S3ObjectInputStream s3ImageResource = ... 
    StreamResource res = new StreamResource("filename.jpg", () -> {
        InputStream is = s3ImageResource;
        return is;
    });
    Image image = new Image(res,"Image");
```

Alternatively if that does not work, based on other questions here in StackOverflow, I assume you can convert S3ObjectInputStream to byte array.

```
    byte[] bytes = // get bytes from S3ObjectInputStream 
    StreamResource res = new StreamResource("filename.jpg", () -> {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return is;
    });
    Image image = new Image(res,"Image");
```